# Reading interface descriptor for a new USB device

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I am understanding [usb_new_device()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2508) function.
I have a question related to [usb_enumerate_device()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2389) function calling inside usb_new_device().

As per the comments above the [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2376), it reads configs/intfs/otg. But I didn't see in the function definition that it is reading the interface descriptor.

It seems the function is reading config descriptor and doing something for OTG devices. I am not seeing the source related to interface descriptor reading. I am missing something here.
linux

Comment: `usb_enumerate_device()` => `usb_get_configuration()` => `usb_parse_configuration()` => `usb_parse_interface()`.

Comment: I think `usb_parse_configuration()` and `usb_parse_interface()` functions are to parse the descriptors, which already read from the device. I could see `usb_get_descriptor(dev, USB_DT_CONFIG, cfgno,bigbuffer,length)` call inside `usb_get_configuration()` is submitting control message to the device to read configuration descriptor. As the comment against `usb_enumerate_device()` says Read descriptors, I am looking for a call to `usb_get_descriptor()` with `USB_DT_INTERFACE` as argument.

Comment: The interface descriptors and endpoint descriptors are embedded in the configuration descriptor.

Comment: So, all USB devices should return all descriptors except device descriptor when there is a get configuration request(for a specific configuration number) from USB host?

Comment: As it says in section 9.4.3 of the USB 3.1 spec, "The standard request to a device supports four types of descriptors: device, configuration, BOS (Binary device Object Store), and string." (For USB 2.0 there are no BOS descriptors, so only three types of descriptors are supported.)

Comment: And in the same section, "A request for a configuration descriptor returns the configuration descriptor, all interface descriptors, endpoint descriptors and endpoint companion descriptors (when operating at Gen X speed) for all of the interfaces in a single request."